How to prevent random 302 canonical-ish redirect on custom template
I'm trying to create a subpost location - like /embed or /feed - for photo galleries.
// this defines the location logic
if (!function_exists('is_gallery')) {
function is_gallery() {
    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $parts = array_values(array_filter(explode('/',$uri)));
        if(end($parts) == 'gallery') {
        return true;
        }
    }
}

// this loads the template
add_action('template_include','gallery_page');
function gallery_page($template) {
    if(is_gallery()) {
        status_header(201);
            global $wp_query;
            $wp_query->is_404  = false;
            $wp_query->is_singular  = true;
        $new_template = locate_template(array('gallery.php'));
        if ('' != $new_template) {return $new_template;}
    }
return $template;
}

So whatever the template outputs is available at example.com/post-name/gallery
It works fine like this, but notice the 201 (could be 203 as well) http status header. If I use the appropriate 200, it no longer works, as wordpress does some random 302 redirect, usually to the parent url but not always.
What I'm trying to do is prevent that redirection. It's possibly triggered by wp_safe_redirect() in wp-includes/pluggable.php but from there I couldn't figure out a filter to stop it.
Disabling canonical redirects – with add_filter('redirect_canonical', '__return_false'); or it's 'remove...' variations – doesn't help either.
And neither does setting true some random values of wp_query, but maybe there's something I'm missing.
So what I want is to stop that redirection or somehow have this work with a proper status of 200.

what you're trying to implement is called a rewrite endpoint and there's already an API for adding them:  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_endpoint/ and https://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2012/06/07/rewrite-endpoints-api/ you don't need to build it from scratch
